# Modifications to the layout engine must not be performed from a background thread after it has been accessed from the main thread."

Tags: swift, grand-central-dispatch

I have a crash on my app " Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Modifications to the layout engine must not be performed from a background thread after it has been accessed from the main thread."

I'm download an mp4 file from url and when it successfully saves the file in library it crashes on print the message. Code is attached:

```
Code crashes after if completed { }

func downloadVideoLinkAndCreateAsset(videoLink: String?) {
    
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        if let url = URL(string: videoLink ?? ""),
           let urlData = NSData(contentsOf: url) {
            let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0];
            let filePath="\(documentsPath)/tempFile.mp4"
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                urlData.write(toFile: filePath, atomically: true)
                PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
                    PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromVideo(atFileURL: URL(fileURLWithPath: filePath))
                }) { completed, error in
                    if completed {
                        self.removeAllOverlays()
                        print( "Video is Saved in Library")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    
}
```

Comment: `PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges` will run asynchronously on the background thread. You need to run code within if completed bloc on the main thread by calling `DispatchQueue.main.async` at that point. Basically you are calling it prematurely in your code.

Comment: Unrelated to the question at hand, don’t use `NSData` from Swift. Also avoid loading large assets, such as videos, into RAM at one time. See https://gist.github.com/robertmryan/3e9ac3950e3a545268f38170733caacb.

Answer (score 0):

The `performChanges` [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phphotolibrary/1620743-performchanges) says,

> Photos executes both the change block and the completion handler block on an arbitrary serial queue. To update your app’s UI as a result of a change, dispatch that work to the main queue.

So, inside the `performChanges` closure, perform the `DispatchQueue.main.async` of the UI update.

So, instead of:

```swift
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    urlData.write(toFile: filePath, atomically: true)
    PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges {
        PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromVideo(atFileURL: URL(fileURLWithPath: filePath))
    } completionHandler: { completed, error in
        if completed {
            self.removeAllOverlays()
            print( "Video is Saved in Library")
        }
    }
}
```

You want:

```swift
urlData.write(toFile: filePath, atomically: true)
PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges {
    PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromVideo(atFileURL: URL(fileURLWithPath: filePath))
} completionHandler: { completed, error in
    if completed {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.removeAllOverlays()
        }
        print( "Video is Saved in Library")
    }
}
```